# Changing a variable though a pointer to a structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to change a int variable through a structure that constant a pointer to other structure which one field is that variable.
I get one warning and one error in the compilation. Anyone can explain why and how can I do his using this code?

The code is:

```
typedef struct
{
    struct TEEC_Session *ptr_struct;
} Context_model;

typedef struct
{   int t_S;    
} Session_model;

void Attribution(Context_model* context,Session_model* session )
{
    (*context).ptr_struct = session;  

}

void change_t_S(Context_model* context )
{
    (*(*context).ptr_struct).t_S = 5; // I Want to change t_S to 5 using only the 

context structure

} 

main()
{
Context_model context;
Session_model session;

Attribution(&context,&session);

// Now I want to change t_S using the context 
change_t_S(&context);
}
```

Comment: I retagged this as C, since that's what the syntax looked like- but if  it's C++ or something else, feel free to retag it.

Comment: What does the `TEEC_Session` structure look like? Besides that, you probably want to use `ptr->element` instead of `(*ptr).element` for readability.

Comment: Your `Context_model` struct contains one member that is supposed to be a `TEEC_Session*`, but you're assigning a `Session_model*` to it without a cast, which should cause a warning. As @matthias points out, a `TEEC_Session` may not have `t_S` member, which would in turn cause an error.

Comment: What are the warning and error messages? Do you mean to have `TEEC_Session` actually a `Session_model`?

Answer (score 0):

modify the definition of Context_model as

```
typedef struct
{
    Session_model *ptr_struct;
} Context_model;
```

and move it below the definition of Session_model.

struct TEEC_Session not defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your `ptr_struct` as having `struct TEEC_Session *` type, but then attempting to use it as a pointer of `Session_model *` type. That's an obvious type mismatch. That just doesn't make sense.

What is `struct TEEC_Session`? There's no other mention of `TEEC_Session` in your entire program. Why did you declare your `ptr_struct` field as a pointer to some completely random  off-the-wall type `struct TEEC_Session`, and then completely forget about the existence of that `struct TEEC_Session`?

If your `struct TEEC_Session` type was supposed to be synonymous with `Session_model` type, you should have to told the compiler about that. For example, you could've declared `Session_model` as

```
typedef struct TEEC_Session
{   
   int t_S;    
} Session_model;
```

and everything would work as intended.

Alternatively, you can get rid of any references to `TEEC_Session` entirely by reordering your declarations

```
typedef struct
{   
  int t_S;    
} Session_model;    

typedef struct
{
  Session_model *ptr_struct;
} Context_model;
```

Finally, you are using C99-style comments in your code (`//`). C99 does not allow declaring functions without explicit return type. `main()` should be `int main()`.

Answer (score 0):

I show the code with additional declaration and the pointer dereferencing idiom.

This compiles ok in C, HTH.

```
struct TEEC_Session;

typedef struct
{ struct TEEC_Session *ptr_struct;
} Context_model;

typedef struct TEEC_Session
{ int t_S;
} Session_model;

void Attribution(Context_model* context,Session_model* session )
{
    context->ptr_struct = session;
}

void change_t_S(Context_model* context )
{
    context->ptr_struct->t_S = 5; // I Want to change t_S to 5 using only the context structure
}

int main_change_var(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Context_model context;
    Session_model session;

    Attribution(&context,&session);

    // Now I want to change t_S using the context
    change_t_S(&context);

    return 0;
}
```